# Maximize expected score of a ranking

Tags: ranking, rating

I am trying to figure out how to answer 1.1.c from here http://www.cc.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/200808_cse_qualifier.pdf.  The problem setup is as follows [image]

We are then asked to show
[image]

An earlier problem had us show that the maximizing ranking is in descending order of $y$ values.  My intuition is that in expectation, if $y_i>y_j$, then in expectation, $p(y_i|x_i)>p(y_i|x_j)$, so that (with a big hand wave) in expectation $R(x_i)>R(x_j)$, but I'm having a hard time formalizing that or saying much about the other terms in the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend showed me how to answer this.  The expectation, using independence assumptions and marginalization arguments, is given by
\begin{align}
\sum_{y_1}\sum_{y_2}\cdots\sum_{y_n}(c_1 y_{\sigma_1}+\cdots+c_n y_{\sigma_n})&p(y_1,\cdots,y_n|x_1,\cdots,x_n)\\
&=c_1\sum_{y}y_{\sigma_1}p(y_{\sigma_1}|x_{\sigma_1})+\cdots +c_n\sum_{y}y_{\sigma_n}p(y_{\sigma_n}|x_{\sigma_n})\\
\end{align}

using the descending order of $R(x)$'s will give us the max based on the previous problem.